# tvOS Simulator. Trigger iCloud Sync not implemented?

Tags: xcode, synchronization, icloud, tvos

I can manually trigger iCloud syncing within an iOS app but I just get the following error when attempting it on tvOS:

[image: Xcode Error]

Has iCloud for tvOS been implemented within the Xcode simulator?